# PHP get PUT request body

Tags: php, json, rest

I'm currently developing a Restful Json-API in PHP. I want to send a PUT-Request to `items/:id` to update a record. The data will be transferred as `application/json`.

I want to call the API with

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{"example" : "data"}' "http://localhost/items/someid"
```

On the server side, I'm not able the retrieve the request body. I tried

```
file_get_contents("php://input");
```

but this returns an empty string. Also a `fopen()`/`fread()` combination doesn't work.

When calling via POST, everything works great, I can read the json perfectly on the server side. But the API isn't Restful anymore. Does anyone have a solution for this? Is there another way to send and receive Json?

btw, I'm developing the API with the [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/).

Comment: Did you try fopen("php://input", "r")?

Comment: Awesome that you're using slim.  I hope you're having good experiences.  I've really enjoyed my SLIM restful api creation

Comment: [This comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php#59720) in the manual suggests that you might need to sent the Content-Length header (not sure if cURL will do this automatically...) and use `fopen`, rather than `file_get_contents`. No idea how accurate that is, but it might be worth an attempt...

Comment: curl does send the Content-Length header, and also when sending it manually, nothing changes. Also fopen doesn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`php://input` is only readable once for PUT requests:

> Note: A stream opened with php://input can only be read once; the stream does not support seek operations. However, depending on the SAPI implementation, it may be possible to open another php://input stream and restart reading. This is only possible if the request body data has been saved. Typically, this is the case for POST requests, but not other request methods, such as PUT or PROPFIND.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

The Slim framework already reads the data upon request. Take the data from the Request object, into which it has been read.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my issue. I can get the raw data with $app->request->getBody(); and then do a json_decode. I wasn't aware of this method, since it isnt in the documentation.

Comment: +1 this was my problem using the restTonic PHP framework.  The $this->request->data variable already held the PUT body.  I had read php://input in my POST handler and couldn't see why the PUT handler couldn't use the same method to handle its body.

Answer (score 2):

> On the server side, I'm not able the retrieve the request body. I tried file_get_contents("php://input");

You can only use `file_get_contents( 'php://input', 'r' );` once per request. Retrieving its values will truncate the values as well, so if you call it twice, it'll return an empty string. Slim's request object contains the values you need, so:

```
<?php
$app = new Slim( );

$app->put( '/items/someid', function () use ( $app ) {
    echo $app->request( )->put( 'example' ); // should display "data".
});
```

Comment: This is true for url-encoded data, but not for raw json. if I send the data url encoded, I can access it via Slim's request object. doesn't work for json tough.

Comment: The issue remains; you can only read from php://input *once*, and Slim has already done that. You'll have to use Slim's request object to get your values.

Comment: Apparently the Slim Framework reads the request body upon construction, so php://input was already deleted. thx!

Comment: @aladin That was what I was trying to convey, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The example from the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php) uses fopen to access php://input in read mode.  Have you tried doing it that way instead?

EDIT: The [manual page for PHP://](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) says some stuff that seems to suggest that PUT data might not be available in some cases!

> Note: A stream opened with php://input can only be read once; the
>   stream does not support seek operations. However, depending on the
>   SAPI implementation, it may be possible to open another php://input
>   stream and restart reading. This is only possible if the request body
>   data has been saved. Typically, this is the case for POST requests,
>   but not other request methods, such as PUT or PROPFIND.

I don't know where this will leave you regarding PUT processing.  One page seems to say it's possible, the other seems to imply that it won't work under the wrong set of circumstances

Answer (score -1):

I was reading the SLIM framework documentation the other day and it said that some browsers have problems with PUT and DELETE.

Excerpt:

Unfortunately, modern browsers do not provide native support for PUT requests. To work around this limitation, ensure your HTML form’s method is “post”, then add a method override parameter to your HTML form like this:

```
<form action="/books/1" method="post">
    ... other form fields here...
    <input type="hidden" name="_METHOD" value="PUT"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Update Book"/>
</form>
```

Source: http://www.slimframework.com/documentation/stable

Comment: The OP is using Curl to perform the HTTP PUT operation.

Comment: I'm a bit new to this as well, but does cURL just forgo the browser issue?  What if he is doing the curl request via PHP and that is the command line equivalent? (I'm not saying he is, I'm saying would the command line cURL benefit still exist)

Comment: @Jake: yes, using cURL forgoes the browser issue.  No browser is involved the way he's calling the service.

Comment: curl generates raw HTTP requests and you have full control over every last detail of the request. PUT/POST is just an HTTP verb which you can set with `-X PUT` on the command line and similar flags in other wrappers. Yes, curl supports PUT, only browsers don't.