# Jquery ajax: data arriving to server with "POST", but not arriving with "PUT"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, put

I am consuming a service from a REST api, and all types of request except "PUT" work. Apparently, when using PUT, the headers (data)  are not arriving to the server, so authentication is no possible. If I send the data in a query string inside the url, the server behaves as expected.
Why is the data not getting there?

```
// here is my ajax POST call.. it works as expected
function testPost(deviceId, segmentId) {
    console.log('inside testPost function');
    var url = "http://........../api/avoidsegments/" + deviceId;
        $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        data : {
            "appID": ig_appID,
            "clientCode": ig_clientCode,
            "segmentID": segmentId,
        },
        success: function(output) { 
            console.log(output);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log('url: ', url);
            console.log('error: ', err);
        }
    });
}
```

And, here is the put request (I basically copied and pasted post, and changed the method type).. Why does this not send the data to the server??

```
function testPut(deviceId, segmentId) {
    console.log('inside testPut function');
    var url = "http://........../api/avoidsegments/" + deviceId;
        $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        data : {
            "appID": ig_appID,
            "clientCode": ig_clientCode,
            "segmentID": segmentId,
        },
        success: function(output) { 
            console.log(output);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log('url: ', url);
            console.log('error: ', err);
        }
    });
}
```

Whenever I use "PUT", I get a 401... because the data is not arriving. I checked  $_GET and $_POST where the put is handled and they are empty. 
If I send the data in a query string, put works as expected... I just doesn't work when I send headers.

I'd appreciate if anyone could point me towards the right direction so I can fix this problem.

Comment: check this [php-get-put-request-body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684315/php-get-put-request-body)

Comment: Response code 401 means "Unauthorized". I would expect some other 4XX response, if the server wouldn't get expected data. Or maybe you need `https` instead `http`?